# Речевые ошибки

Tags: лексика

Как исправить данные предложения? Ошибки основаны на использовании многозначностислов и омонимов.
1). Торговая премьера состоялась в новом микрорайоне.
2). Чацкий замечает, что Молчалин "дойдет до степеней известных".
3). При цитировании стихов в сочинении допускаются некоторые неточночти. 
4). результаты контрольных работ, проведенных в разных городах, были отличные.
5). Из-за рассеянности шахматист не раз во время чемпионата терял очки.
6). Как известно, чтение Гоголя никого из его современников не оставляло равнодушным.

Answer (score 4):

Домашнее задание?

Коль ошибки основаны на многозначности и омонимии, то каждое предложение можно исправить как минимум двумя способами. Первое предложение не поняла. Что такое "торговая премьера"? Новый магазин? Торговый центр? Обратите внимание во втором предложении на слово "замечает", в третьем на слово "допускается", в четвертом - на слово "отличные" , в пятом - на "очки", в шестом - на "чтение Гоголя". Дерзайте, и получится! А мы поправим, если что не так.

Comment: Да, домашнее задание. Учебник Грекова 10-11 кл.
1)Тоже не поняла, что за торговая премьера. Может, открытие магазина?
2)отмечает?
3)допускают?
4)очень хорошими?
5)баллы?
6)произведения Гоголя?